# Merge two data frames from a national survey with panel and not panel individuals of two different years (in r)

Tags: r, merge

I tried to search on the website but I didn't find the answer to my question; if there is already one please write the link.

I have two data frames from a national survey: each year I have some families that have already been interviewed and others that are new. I want to merge the data frames in order to have only the families present in both data frames and match them in order to have the 2014 values in a row and the 2012 values in the next one for each individual (for the sake of semplicity I omitted other social variables present in the survey).

For example: df1 and df2

```
> df1 <- data.frame(nquest=c(173, 526, 1066, 1066), nord=c(1,1,1,2), year=c(2014, 2014, 2014, 2014))
> structure(df1)
   nquest nord  year
1    173    1   2014
2    526    1   2014
3   1066    1   2014
4   1066    2   2014

> df2 <- data.frame(nquest=c(173, 526, 3456, 3456), nord=c(1,1,1,2), year=c(2012, 2012, 2012, 2012))
> structure(df2)
  nquest nord year
1    173    1 2012
2    526    1 2012
3   3456    1 2012
4   3456    2 2012
```

where nquest is the number of the family and nord the component of the family (ex. 1 father, 2 mother).

I want to merge them in this way:

```
> df <- data.frame(nquest=c(173, 173, 526,526), nord=c(1,1,1,1), year=c(2014, 2012, 2014, 2012))
> structure(df)
  nquest nord year
1    173    1 2014
2    173    1 2012
3    526    1 2014
4    526    1 2012
```

I tried the to merge them:

```
tot <- merge (df1, df2, by=c("nquest", "nord")
structure(tot)
  nquest nord  year.x  year.y
1    173    1   2014    2012
2    526    1   2014    2012
```

and I tried the rbind function:

```
> tot <- rbind(s, df2)
> structure(tot)
  nquest nord year
1    173    1  201
2    526    1 2014
3   1066    1 2014
4   1066    2 2014
5    173    1 2012
6    526    1 2012
7   3456    1 2012
8   3456    2 2012
```

Thank you

Comment: Using just base R and nothing clever, you could do `tot <- rbind(df1[df1$nquest %in% df2$nquest, ], df2[df2$nquest %in% df1$nquest, ])`. That will first filter each data frame to only contain the rows of data for families in both data frames, and then rbind them together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an approach using "dplyr", there is probably a better way to do the filtering though

```
bind_rows(df1, df2) %>% 
  filter( nquest %in% df1$nquest & nquest %in% df2$nquest) %>%
  arrange(nquest, desc(year))
```

The second condition on the "arrange" function, that specifies year, is not necessary in this case but I am putting it there for completness

Comment: Thank you for the answers; I have a new question: if I want to merge taking into consideration also nord? It is possible that from an year to another the number of components change

Comment: As in nord and nquest also appears in both sets?

Comment: Yes, for example in 2012 a family is composed by 4 persons (parents and two sons) and in 2014 it is composed by 2 persons (only parents, the sons left home)

Comment: Include additional constraints in the filter expression separated by &